# pandas function isin didn't work with data-frame inside def method

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to function as the below:

```
        sql_DF['vendor'] = np.where(sql_DF.site_id.isin(hua_sites_df['Site ID']), "HUA",
                                                    "ESN")
```

but it doesn't work, this function supposed to updated column called `vendor` in database after `read_sql`.

So here's my full code:

```
from os import environ
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.types import Integer, Text, String, DateTime
import pandas as pd
import os
from database import connec
import numpy as np


kanban_excel = "Site Integration Kanban_Netherlands KPN Mobile Network Modernization Project__20200207225328.xlsx"
db_schema = environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_DB_SCHEMA')
def push_all_sites_to_sql():
    all_sitesexcel = 'All_Sites_GSM_UMTS.xlsx'
    def prepare_data():
        """Create DataFrame and clean column names."""
        jobs_DF = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),all_sitesexcel), usecols=['Vendor','Site_ID'], sheet_name='Sheet2')
        new_columns = [column.replace(' ', '_').lower() for column in jobs_DF]
        jobs_DF.columns = new_columns
        return jobs_DF


    def upload_dataframe_to_sql(jobs_DF):
        """Upload data to db with proper dtypes."""
        jobs_DF.to_sql("all_sites_he",
                       connec.engine,
                       if_exists='append',
                       schema=db_schema,
                       index=False,
                       chunksize=500,
                       dtype={
                           'Vendor': Integer,
                           'Site_ID': Integer,
                       })


    def get_dataframe_from_sql(table_name):
        """Create DataFrame form SQL table."""
        sql_DF = pd.read_sql_table(table_name,
                                   con=connec.engine,
                                   )
        kanban_sites = 'Site Integration Kanban_Netherlands KPN Mobile Network Modernization Project__20200207225328.xlsx'
        hua_sites_df = pd.read_excel(kanban_sites, sheet_name='gsclist1', header=1)
        sql_DF['vendor'] = np.where(sql_DF.site_id.isin(hua_sites_df['Site ID']), "HUA",
                                                    "ESN")
        return sql_DF



    jobs_DF = prepare_data()
    print(jobs_DF.info())
    upload_dataframe_to_sql(jobs_DF)
    get_dataframe_from_sql('all_sites_he')

push_all_sites_to_sql()
```

So the problem in this part:

```
    def get_dataframe_from_sql(table_name):
        """Create DataFrame form SQL table."""
        sql_DF = pd.read_sql_table(table_name,
                                   con=connec.engine,
                                   )
        kanban_sites = 'Site Integration Kanban_Netherlands KPN Mobile Network Modernization Project__20200207225328.xlsx'
        hua_sites_df = pd.read_excel(kanban_sites, sheet_name='gsclist1', header=1)
        sql_DF['vendor'] = np.where(sql_DF.site_id.isin(hua_sites_df['Site ID']), "HUA",
                                                    "ESN")
        return sql_DF
```

this line doesn't execute:

```
        sql_DF['vendor'] = np.where(sql_DF.site_id.isin(hua_sites_df['Site ID']), "HUA",
                                                    "ESN")
```

How Can I solve this.... I know there's a simple trick but I can't find it..
Hope someone helps me

## Edited:

`print(get_dataframe_from_sql(table_name='all_sites_he'))`

```
        vendor  site_id
0          NaN        4
1          NaN        5
2          NaN        7
3          NaN        8
4          NaN        9
...        ...      ...
242635     NaN     2956
242636     NaN     2969
242637     NaN     2970
242638     NaN     2971
242639     NaN     2972
```

`print(get_dataframe_from_sql)`

`<function push_all_sites_to_sql.<locals>.get_dataframe_from_sql at 0x00000276EB444F70>`

## Edited 2:

So now I updated this part and put this function before as the below code:

```
def push_all_sites_to_sql():
    all_sitesexcel = 'All_Sites_GSM_UMTS.xlsx'
    def prepare_data():
        """Create DataFrame and clean column names."""
        jobs_DF = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),all_sitesexcel), usecols=['Vendor','Site_ID'], sheet_name='Sheet2',dtype={
        'Vendor': float,
        'Site_ID': int,
    })
        new_columns = [column.replace(' ', '_').lower() for column in jobs_DF]
        jobs_DF.columns = new_columns
        kanban_sites = 'Site Integration Kanban_Netherlands KPN Mobile Network Modernization Project__20200207225328.xlsx'
        hua_sites_df = pd.read_excel(kanban_sites, sheet_name='gsclist1', header=1)
        jobs_DF['vendor'] = jobs_DF["vendor"].round(4).apply(str)
        jobs_DF['vendor'] = np.where(jobs_DF.site_id.isin(hua_sites_df['Site ID']),
                                             "HUA", "ESN")
        return jobs_DF
```

but I found this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1225, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_executemany(
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mssql\pyodbc.py", line 401, in do_executemany
    super(MSDialect_pyodbc, self).do_executemany(
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 585, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Error converting data type nvarchar to float. (8114) (SQLExecDirectW)')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/haroo501/PycharmProjects/ToolUpdated/app.py", line 19, in <module>
    all_sites.push_all_sites_to_sql()
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\ToolUpdated\excel_to_sql\all_sites.py", line 57, in push_all_sites_to_sql
    upload_dataframe_to_sql(jobs_DF)
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\ToolUpdated\excel_to_sql\all_sites.py", line 33, in upload_dataframe_to_sql
    jobs_DF.to_sql("all_sites_he",
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2653, in to_sql
    sql.to_sql(
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 512, in to_sql
    pandas_sql.to_sql(
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1317, in to_sql
    table.insert(chunksize, method=method)
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 755, in insert
    exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 669, in _execute_insert
    conn.execute(self.table.insert(), data)
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 982, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 293, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1095, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1249, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1476, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 152, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1225, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_executemany(
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mssql\pyodbc.py", line 401, in do_executemany
    super(MSDialect_pyodbc, self).do_executemany(
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 585, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Error converting data type nvarchar to float. (8114) (SQLExecDirectW)')
[SQL: INSERT INTO all_sites_he (vendor, site_id) VALUES (?, ?)]
[parameters: (('ESN', 4), ('ESN', 5), ('ESN', 7), ('ESN', 8), ('ESN', 9), ('ESN', 10), ('ESN', 11), ('ESN', 12)  ... displaying 10 of 500 total bound parameter sets ...  ('ESN', 723), ('HUA', 724))]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Comment: What if you add `.values` as in `hua_sitest_df['Site ID'].values`

Comment: @CeliusStingher thanks for your comment I tried this but dosen't work also I don't know where's the problem as the code doen't give me any error

Comment: Are both tables `sql_DF` and `hua_sitest_df` correctly created?

Comment: @CeliusStingher yes those methods works perfect and create tables in database but the problem after creating the database I have `vendor` column name in database is empty as I need to fill thi column with the method

Comment: The argument to the `isin()` function has to be a list. In your case, trying changing the line to `sql_DF['vendor'] = np.where(sql_DF.site_id.isin(hua_sites_df['Site ID'].tolist()), "HUA","ESN")`

Comment: What is  `push_all_sites_to_sql()` supposed to do? At the moment you don't do anything with the output from `get_dataframe_from_sql`

Comment: @Sajan using `.values` would generate the same effect, so that's not the issue.

Comment: @Sajan still the same problem

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that the argument to isin() function can also be a dictionary or  dataframe.

Comment: @CeliusStingher  ok good I figured that this function works well when I print `print(all_sites_db_df)` but when I check the database there's no update

Comment: That's because the order of the functions is not correct?

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Haroon you are not uploading the result of `get_dataframe_from_sql` anywhere in your code

Comment: @CeliusStingher  I don't know really :(... I hope to find a solution for this I just need to apply this function` all_sites_db_df['vendor'] = np.where(all_sites_db_df.site_id.isin(hua_sites_df['Site ID'].tolist()),
                                             "HUA", "ESN")` to update the database

Comment: @Dan please check edit I uploaded the output

Comment: As @CeliusStingher suggested, the order of the functions might be the issue ? the `get_dataframe_from_sql` function should be called before the `upload_dataframe_to_sql` function ?

Comment: @Sajan Now I think I found a soution for this is to update the `Data-Frame` before importing to `sql`... I have just edited my question could you check!  Do you have any idea about this error?`Error converting data type nvarchar to float.`

Comment: I think the above error might be caused because of mismatch between the field type in sql and that in the dataframe. The error which I am referring to is in the function `push_all_sites_to_sql` where towards the end the inner functions are called. Try changing the order in which they are invoked i.e. first call`get_dataframe_from_sql` and then call `upload_dataframe_to_sql`.